# How to use a tag as a header in Views?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view page where the sort criteria are tag names.

I want to have the appropriate tag-name appear as a `h2` above the content of that type.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or do I have to mess with Twig templates?

Comment: you need to enable grouping by the tag field in setting of your view's style plugin. You can find it under `Format` section of your View. After grouping is enabled, go ahead and exclude the tag field from display. The group header is usually wrapped in H3 (as far as I remember), but you can change that by overriding the theme template for your view

Comment: Wow. That worked! :D Drupal really doesn't like to make things intuitive :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `<h2>` tag under Style Settings of your field.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know but now I have loads of repeating <h2>'s when all I want is one subheading for each different tag name with all the articles with that particular tag name underneath